# Is it possible to modify the installation of a .apk, so that it creates a folder or some different files?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk, android-install-apk

is it possible, that the .apk installs (while it is installing the rest of the app) an folder with some files in it? it would be nice, if the user could install the app, sync it with the programm on the pc (via usb right now... don't ask) without starting the app the first time.

I've searched through the internet for any of this but all things i get are just tutorials how to extract files from the apk or even better, how to install a apk...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, the application can unpack files and folder from assets/ on the first run. But the user must run the application at least once.

OTOH, you may try to create an application that starts when the user attaches the USB cable -- there should be notifications about such events.

Something like:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible, that the .apk installs (while it is installing the rest of the app) an folder with some files in it?

No, sorry.